# Some images get hidden as you resize responsive grid in css

Tags: html, css, grid

I made a responsive css grid for a photo gallery, its resizing perfectly fine however as you reduce the viewport width to less than 525px some images disappear.

I’ve tried every solution I could think of, maybe a separate media query could work for this.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 250px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.b,
.c,
.d,
.e,
.f,
.g {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3G3A5Boa1HXaOLfRX6yQ1fQhCyUeC5JXnfSphFnFWFF8u1LXULJpM03Z9Cg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.a {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSzw1H1XtKHasjDzxhJUAFzOICjKbRiMMrqODW5i5fPs04lSwmV");
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.c {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTK6c3ngsnn2vq9fDYVxdsF-9v8DPbzWYRvKuAY4tR006s2_ncp");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box a"> </div>
  <div class="box b"> </div>
  <div class="box c"> </div>
  <div class="box d"> </div>
  <div class="box e"> </div>
  <div class="box f"> </div>
  <div class="box g"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have introducing the media query in the your file css?

Comment: For the future, leave the code here if it is possible. Please see how to [create an minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably solve the problem of elements disappearing at a lower resolution.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 250px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.b,
.c,
.d,
.e,
.f,
.g {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3G3A5Boa1HXaOLfRX6yQ1fQhCyUeC5JXnfSphFnFWFF8u1LXULJpM03Z9Cg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}

@media(max-width:525px) {

  .a,
  .b,
  .c,
  .d,
  .e,
  .f,
  .g {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
}

.a {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSzw1H1XtKHasjDzxhJUAFzOICjKbRiMMrqODW5i5fPs04lSwmV");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}

.c {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTK6c3ngsnn2vq9fDYVxdsF-9v8DPbzWYRvKuAY4tR006s2_ncp");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box a"> </div>
  <div class="box b"> </div>
  <div class="box c"> </div>
  <div class="box d"> </div>
  <div class="box e"> </div>
  <div class="box f"> </div>
  <div class="box g"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The media query makes all the images take up both columns so they all display? Am i getting that right?

Comment: Not only media query but also `.c` and `grid-column: auto / span 2`;

Answer (score 0):

add media query for your grid because each grid got min width that why its not resizing at small screen. you need to add this to your css:

```
 @media(max-width:525px){
      .grid{
      grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(100%, 1fr));
      }
    }
```